# Looking for advice with dimpling spheres

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

I am fairly new to blender and am stumbling my way through a project I am working on. I have a few dozen sphere meshes with various different aspects and elements that I am fairly happy with. To top things off I am looking to add a particular effect to each sphere that I am struggling with.

I am trying to edit the top of the spheres to have a billowing dimpled effect, like you might find on a pinched balloon or baggy clothing. The general idea is to have the very point at the top pulled down closer to the center of the sphere, and then have alternating smooth rounded ridges taper out a short distance.

Something similar to these:

[image]

[image]

No matter what I try I can't seem to get the desired effect. By directly editing the vertices I usually end up with jagged points and sharp ridges, like a broken Christmas ornament. I have tried various sculpting tools, but that tends to leave me with odd bulges and uneven bumps.

I don't need everything to be exactly symmetrical, but some uniformity is desired. I also only want to edit the top region of the sphere without changing any lower areas. Any suggestions in how to best achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try turning on  proportional editing.

Comment: Please show your current work in a Blender screen capture.  This allows the reader to offer suggestions based potentially on your current work.  Otherwise suggestions become tutorials.

Comment: Like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCYqp.png)?

Comment: Do you know how to select  edges and Checker Deselect?

Comment: @leander That is extremely close to what I am looking to do, only covering less area; maybe only 20% of the top of the sphere. Please, how did you achieve this effect with such smooth elegance?

Comment: Look at the comments of this thread. Yohello and atomicbezier mentioned the tools. Try searching for them.

Comment: Thank you all tremendously. I am getting much closer results than previously, but still having a little bit of trouble getting it just right.

I am able to get a fair and uniform indention, however the billowing effect seems to be causing issues. The two problems I am having are that applying changes to much else beyond the very center point begins to distort the entire sphere, and not just near the area selected. Also I am getting a sort of jagged slope instead of a smooth rounded effect. Any additional help is greatly appreciated.

[see here](https://imgur.com/92FnkCo)